# A 3d printer was gifted, now the gifter wants it back

Tags: return

So my friend is having an issue where his ex employer gave him a 3D printer as a gift. Before accepting the gift he told his employer he could not afford to buy it from him multiple times. The ex employer stated he was giving it to him because he was planning to get a new one anyway. They arranged a time with the ex employer to pick it up from his home even using his business truck. Later in the year the ex employers business fell through and he filed bankruptcy. During this time my friend stopped working for the employer due to non payment. Soon after the ex employer suddenly demands the return of the gifted 3d printer or else he would sue and report it as stolen. There was no agreement made verbally or written for any payment for the printer or return of printer after ending employment. He does not have a formal gift letter/intent of gift receipt. if his ex employer reports it as stolen will he have to give the printer back? Also will theft be on his record?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this because it doesn't ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

The company likely still had the printer listed somewhere as belonging to them and it was demanded during the official bankrupt procedure. They may be forced to behave that way.

While may look contra-intuitive, in case of the bankrupt company members cannot just divide the equipment between themselves. A company usually finish with lots of unpaid invoices, and the equipment is seized by the responsible authority to extract at least some money to cover these debts. How I have seen, everything is stacked in a separate room and the room is then locked. At this stage, somebody notices the printer missing.

The company owner may have not been aware of. It is likely this authority that is pushing to give up the printer now.

I think the company owner attempted to show a good will for you but likely had no experience on the bankruptcy procedures. Give them that printer, you do not have any proof you own it rightfully. Your anger is not in place.

Comment: Strongly disagree with your final sentence. If I give you something as a gift then realise that was a bad idea, that's my problem not yours. If I then demand it back and threaten to sue you and report it as stolen... the anger is more than justified.

Comment: I mean, it is highly unlikely that the employer just had the intention to insult you by giving, then taking the printer.

Comment: Sure, they probably weren't *planning* to threaten to sue OP's friend and falsely accuse them of theft when they handed it over. But who cares whether they *planned* to do so at the time? What matters is that they *are* doing it now. Why would anger possibly be out of place in that situation?

Comment: They just desperately need the printer back.

Comment: ...I understand that. What I don't understand is why you think *threatening to sue somebody and falsely accuse them of stealing it* is a reasonable enough response that it should provoke no anger.

Comment: @ChrisH usually the insolvency regulator files the charges against anyone known to possess apparently missing items of large value. Then in *that* case the alleged person has to identify how they got a hold of the item as defense.

Comment: And you think that means somebody who’s done nothing wrong but is now being threatened with false accusations of criminal behaviour, all because somebody else refuses to face the consequences of their own actions, should not be angry?